# Android apk patch file to large after use d8 dex compiler

Tags: android, patch, dex

I use bsdiff to patch apks that were compile by d8 dex compiler, but the patch file is too large, about 60% compare to the original apk file.

At first I use gradle plugin 3.0.1, and "multiDexEnabled true", and the apk contained about sixty to seventy dex files. And the patch file is very small, about 0.7M, and my apk size is always about 8M.

Several month ago, I changed gradle plugin to 3.1.2. Then I found my apk wase 7.2M, and just only 2 dex files in the apk, but the patch file increase to 4M!

I think it's cause by the d8 dex compiler.

Is there anybody know how to keep sixty to seventy dex files whit d8 dex compiler? Because bsdiff can patch mutch smalller patch file with manny dex files.

Or Is there any other patch tools better than bsdiff?

Answer (score 0):

D8 make dex byte code change more when first time.

you can change some code and make an apk again,then you can use bzdiff compare them. I think they should be change small.

Comment: I have already to tried, I added only one line code, an maked another apk by d8 compiler, the patch file is still too large.

Comment: Ofcourse.I mean you use d8 make apk this time ,it will change a lot because dex change. But if you make apk next time, it will be change small.
If you change one line code and make apk call apk1,then you can chage two line code and make apk call apk2, compare apk1 and apk2.They should bechange small.